# More performant XSLT -- Selective Inclusion in Output

Tags: xslt

I have created a stylesheet that is supposed to selectively copy the contents of an XML document so that I can strip out data that we do not need.  I have provided 2 examples below and the stylesheet that we are currently using to do this.  The stylesheet works, but I think there is probably a better way of doing it because in the current version I check for the same thing in two different locations (author='John Doe').

The rules for including an xml element in the output is as follows:

- If there is a notepad element within notepads that has the author text equal to 'John Doe' then include the notepads element in the output
- If the notepad element has an author element with text equal to 'John Doe' then include all elements within the notepad element in the xml output.

## Input Example #1

```
<transaction>  
<policy>  
    <insco>CC</insco>  
    <notepads>  
      <notepad>  
        <author>Andy</author>  
      <notepad>  
      <notepad>  
        <author>John Doe</author>  
      <notepad>  
      <notepad>  
        <author>Barney</author>  
      <notepad>  
    </notepads>  
  </policy>  
</transaction>
```

## Expected result for Input #1

```
<transaction>
  <policy>
    <insco>CC</insco>
    <notepads>
      <notepad>
        <author>John Doe</author>
      <notepad>
    </notepads>
  </policy>
</transaction>
```

## Input Example #2

```
<transaction>
  <policy>
    <insco>CC</insco>
    <notepads>
      <notepad>
        <author>Andy</author>
      <notepad>
    </notepads>
  </policy>
</transaction>
```

## Expected Result for Input #2

```
<transaction>
  <policy>
    <insco>CC</insco>
  </policy>
</transaction>
```

## Current Version of Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="fn">
  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name()='notepads'">
          <xsl:if test="/transaction/policy/insco='CC' and (notepad/author='John Doe')">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:copy>              
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="name()='notepad'">
          <xsl:if test="author='John Doe'">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:copy>              
          </xsl:if>                
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this.

1) identity template, hard coded author name:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- nodepads generally get removed... -->    
  <xsl:template match="notepad" />

  <!-- ...unless their author is 'Jon Doe' -->    
  <xsl:template match="notepad[author='John Doe']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

2) modified identity template, XSL key, parameterized author name:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:param name="theAuthor" select="'John Doe'" />

  <xsl:key 
    name="kNotepad" match="notepad[author]" 
    use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', author)" 
  />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="
        node()[not(self::notepad)]
        |key('kNotepad', concat(generate-id(), '|', $theAuthor))
        |@*" 
      />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second approach requires a little explanation:

- the `<xsl:key>` indexes all `<nodepad>` nodes that have an `<author>` by their parent's unique ID and the author name
- let's say the unique ID of `<notepads>` is `'id0815'`, then the key to the `<notepad>`s you are interested in would be `'id0815|Jon Doe'`
- the identity template copies every node that is passed through it. It is modified in a way that it does *not* pass every node it finds through itself, but rather only:

  - any node that is not a `<notepad>`: `node()[not(self::notepad)]`
  - any attribute: `@*`
  - any node that is returned by the key.
- the call to `key()` naturally only ever returns anything at all on `<notepads>` elements (because it contains *their* unique ID)
- so when the template is currently processing a `<notepads>` element (`'id0815'` in our case), `key()` will return its `'Jon Doe'` children only, in all other cases it will turn up empty
- in contrast to solution 1) this one can be fed with a parameter, changing its behavior without changing its code
- it is worth noting that everything stays in input document order

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I don't know if the added complexity is worth it (the name shouldn't change or if it does it will change every couple years), but I can definitely see the usefulness of the technique you have displayed here.

Comment: The complexity of both approaches is roughly comparable - of course depending on your familiarity with XSLT. In any case, you decide. ;)

Comment: @Lucero: Yeah, this was not part of the written requirement and I kinda overlooked it in the supplied code sample. Not sure why this is in the example anyway. A template match="transaction" that checks for this and calls apply-templates conditionally would fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Use templates, they're usually more efficient, and avoid `name()` checks, they're slow and unreliable (prefixes and namespaces don't work well with those):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="notepads">
        <xsl:if test="(ancestor::policy/insco='CC') and (notepad/author='John Doe')">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="notepad">
        <xsl:if test="author='John Doe'">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That does look a lot cleaner than the current version.